# Writing a Class Based View that Returns a Model instance made by the authenicated_user

Tags: django, django-views

I am super new to Python and Django and am trying to get the Model instance made by the current user.
I can get the current user.id as the pk but am struggling to find out how to reference that current user and apply that to the View. 
  Currently I have the CustomUser and Profile on a OneToOne Relationship but both are running different pk's ( which makes sense) but while i can get the current users id and apply it through a url its referencing the CustomUser and not the Profile. 
   So i have this View being accessed by a button in a User Inferface that is supposed to call the Profile instance in a DetailView and then a follow on UpdateView

```
       class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
class Meta:
    pass

def __str__(self):
    return f"Username: {self.username}, PK: {self.id}"
```

class Profile(models.Model):

```
# TODO: Define fields here


# add additional templates under templates/users. Add to the tuples below in this format.
USER_TEMPLATES = (
    ('users/generic/generic.html', ('generic')),
    ('users/clothing/clothing.html',('clothing')) 
)


#model fields

author = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable = False, related_name = 'user')
title = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Company Name', max_length= 50)
slug = models.SlugField(editable=False,max_length = settings.SLUG_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH)
st_address = models.CharField( max_length=50, verbose_name = 'Street Address')
city = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 50, verbose_name = 'City')
state = USStateField(default = 'TN', blank=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length=15)
contact_name = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Contact Person Name', null = True, blank = True, max_length=50)
contact_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'Contact Person Email', null = True, blank = True, max_length=254)
contact_phone = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Best Phone Number to Contact', null = True, blank = True, max_length=50, help_text = "Business Phone (XXX) XXX-XXXX")
aboutus = models.TextField(null= True, blank= True, help_text="Write about a paragraph about who you are and the good things your business does.")
greeting = models.TextField(null= True, blank= True, help_text = "Write about a paragraph telling who you are to greet your customers on the front page of your website.")
logo = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to='pic_folder/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=300)
template = models.CharField(choices = USER_TEMPLATES, default = 'users/generic/generic.html', max_length=50)
facebook = models.URLField(blank = True, max_length=200)
instagram = models.URLField(blank = True, max_length=200)
twitter = models.URLField(blank = True, max_length=200)


# absolute url
def get_absolute_url(self):

    kwargs = {
        'pk': self.id,
        'slug': self.slug
    }
    return reverse ('profile-pk-slug-detail', kwargs=kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    value = self.title
    self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Meta:
    """Meta definition for Profile."""

    verbose_name = 'Profile'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

def __str__(self):
    """Unicode representation of Profile."""
    return f"Company Name: {self.title} Slug: {self.pk}-{self.slug} Type: {self.template}"
```

Class Based View:
I have tried to get the authenicated user id which i can get and im thinking i need to get it through a queryset of some type but then i get stuck.

```
    class CompanyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = Profile
fields = '__all__'
query_pk_and_slug = True
template_name = "users/interface/profile_detail.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile'] = Profile.objects.all()
    return context
# For example, if you want to return to a certain user
# profile (which requires url adjustments to take a Primary Key)
def get_success_url(self):
    user_id = self.request.user.id # Get user_id from request
    return reverse_lazy('users:userindex', kwargs={'id': user_id})

def get_queryset(self):
    return Profile.objects.filter(author_id=self.request.user)
```

Here is the CreateProfileView that makes the Profile model.

```
      class CreateProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
'''creates a new UserProfile Model, only one allowed per customer atm'''
modelform = ProfileForm
model = Profile
fields = ['title', 'st_address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_phone']
query_pk_and_slug = True

success_url = reverse_lazy('users:userindex')
template_name = 'users/interface/profile_form.html'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile'] = Profile.objects.all()
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**EDIT:  The Answer to anyone running across this**

The problem was in the get_success_url which was

```
def get_success_url(self):
    user_id = self.request.user.id# Get user_id from request
    return reverse_lazy('users:userindex', kwargs={'id': user_id})
```

and should have been

```
def get_success_url(self):
    profile_id = request.user.profile.pk # Get user_id from request
    return reverse_lazy('users:userindex', kwargs={'id': profile_id})
```

and it was called using this url

```
path('userdetail-<int:pk>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='userprofile')
```

with this tag

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'users:userprofile' user.profile.pk %}">Company Profile</a>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where you are having the problem. If it's in the `get_success_url` method, then you want `request.user.user.pk` to get the profile's pk. The second `user` is because you have `related_name='user'`. Since the related name is used to go from a user to the profile, it would be better to remove that. It will default to  `related_name='profile'`, then you use `request.user.profile.pk to get the profile pk.

Comment: ahh... that does make sense. ill try that Thank You

Comment: well that wasnt it. Its still referencing the Custom User id and not the Model id.

Comment: okay, i think im figuring it out. I had to change a few more things but im getting the correct pk for the model now. You were correct about using the request.user.profile.pk . I just needed to change some of the referencing tempate tags and some urls to reflect that

Comment: I appreciate the help Alasdair, Ive been stuck on this for a few days trying to figure it out

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please add your solution as a separate answer - that way it will be clearer to readers that you've solved the problem.